# Infinite loop using AndroidKeyStore authentication

Tags: android, infinite-loop, digital-signature, android-keystore

My application enters an infinite loop when I use the AndroidKeyStore requiring user authentication to use the keys

```
.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true);
.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(60);
```

It is assumed that an operation that uses a user's private key requires that the device has been unlocked, otherwise a `UserNotAuthenticatedException` is generated. The app must present the device authentication screen, and the next usage of the key will work.

**But, in my case always is thrown `UserNotAuthenticatedException` forcing app to show the unlock screen**. It only happens in some devices. I have two Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 and only fails in one of them.

This is the main code of the activity

```
KeyPair keyPair;

private void attemptRegisterKey(){
    try{
        //generate key pair using AndroidKeyStore only once.
        if (keyPair != null)
            generateKeyPair(alias);

        //Sample Signature
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        sig.update("hello".getBytes());
        byte signature[] = sig.sign();

    }catch  (UserNotAuthenticatedException e){
        //show Authentication Screen
        Intent intent = mKeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS) {
        // Challenge completed, proceed
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            attemptRegisterKey();
        } else {
            //Process error
        }
    }
}
```

---

And the code to generate the key

```
public KeyPair generateKeyPair(String alias) throws Exception {

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");


    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder =  new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        alias,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true);
            .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(60);


    kpg.initialize(builder.build());

            KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    return kp;
}
```

Comment: Hi, we are facing the same issue on a wide range of devices. Do you have any findings on this? I suspect this is a bug in android.

Comment: @Yashavi, finally we decided to present the authentication manually to avoid the problem. I also think it's a bug in some devices

Comment: yeah, that's what I think. I was just thinking that presenting the auth manually defeats the purpose of setting that key's property. Anyways, thank you for quick response.